# how to use callback in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter and I want to create validation for `name` field if the `name` exists in my table. ut I'm getting blank screen, can everyone help me?

this is my controller:

```
public function insertCabang(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'nama_cabang', 'trim|required|callback_isNameExist');


}   

public function isNameExist($name) {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $is_exist = $this->cabang_model->isNameExist($name);

    if ($is_exist) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('isNameExist', 'Name is already exist.');    
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this is my model

```
public function isNameExist($name) {
        $this->db->select('nama_cabang');
        $this->db->where('nama_cabang', $name);
        $query = $this->db->get('master_cabang');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

After submit I get the blank screen.

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Are you calling your function recursively on purpose? Because I didn't understand why.

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting using `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
  error_reporting(E_ERROR);` and let us know what error did you see there?
It may be database error as your code looks perfect.

Comment: i just parse the $query variable and check whether the name is valid in table using num_rows function, i guess it's make sense but i don't know why i get the blank screen..am i wrong ?

Comment: PSA: Stop Using codeigniter immediately.

Comment: thanks :) i've just learn codeigniter

Comment: `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('myform');
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `is_unique` to perform this action instead of using callback.
Your syntax will be

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'nama_cabang', 'trim|required|is_unique[master_cabang.nama_cabang]');
```

Comment: i've just try your code, but i get the same blank screen..or, do you know how to show this error, because i use ini_set('display_errors', 'on');  and the error didn't show

Comment: can you use `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` in index.php and see the error ?

Comment: public function insertCabang(){
  $this->load->library('form_validation');
  $c = $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required|callback_isNameExist');
  if($c){
   echo "Valid";
  }else{
   echo "inValid";
  }
 } i am modify the code, and i'm getting the "Valid"

Comment: `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->load->view('myform');
  }
  else
  {
   $this->load->view('formsuccess');
  }` can you load the view after checking validation? by using previous syntax instead of valid / invalid

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your `insertCabang()` controller function. You run the 
validation, but what should it do after? You must echo the result, or load some view.

```
public function insertCabang(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'nama_cabang', 'trim|required|callback_isNameExist');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        echo 'validated ok';
    }else{echo validation_errors();}
}
```